# php create new array adding distinct values from existing one

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose i have 2 arrays:

```
$array1 =( [0] => Array ( [user] => 'aaa' [count] => '123' )
           [1] => Array ( [user] => 'bbb' [count] => '456' )
           [2] => Array ( [user] => 'ccc' [count] => '789' ) );

$array2= ( [0] => aaa) 
           [1] => ccc );
```

I would like to search values from second array in first array and create the third array that will contain all elements from first array, like this:

```
$array3 =( [0] => Array ( [user] => 'aaa' [count] => '123' )
           [1] => Array ( [user] => 'ccc' [count] => '789' ) );
```

Please help. Thank you in advance
(sorry for bad english)

Comment: What have you tried? If you haven't tried anything yet, take a look at [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: hi. I have tried `foreach`, but i am basic php user, that builds code with examples only. So `foreach` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array1 = array(
   array( 'user' => 'aaa', 'count' => 123 ),
   array( 'user' => 'bbb', 'count' => 456 ),
   array( 'user' => 'ccc', 'count' => 789 ),   
);

$array2 = array('aaa', 'ccc'); 

var_dump(array_filter($array1, function($el) use($array2) {
   return in_array($el['user'], $array2); 
}));
```

It preserves keys, you can reset them if needed. Or with `foreach` loop

```
$out = array();

foreach($array1 as $el)
{
    if (in_array($el['user'], $array2))
       $out[] = $el;
}

var_dump($out);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just tested and worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

Can try using `foreach()`. Example here...

```
$array3 = array();
foreach($array2 as $search){
    foreach($array1 as $val){
        if($search == $val['user']){
            $array3[] = $val;
        }
    }
}
print_r($array3);
```